# Get selected value from Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Hi guys how can one get selected value?

Here is my model

```
public class PaymentModels
{
    public int CreditCardNumber { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> CardType { get; set; }

    public static List<SelectListItem> getCardTypes()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> cardType = new List<SelectListItem>();
        cardType.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "American Express"});
        cardType.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mastercard" });
        cardType.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Visa" });

        return cardType;
    }
}
```

This is how the list is shown on view via controller

```
ViewData["List"] = PaymentModels.getCardTypes();
```

And here is my post back method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Payment(PaymentModels pay)
{
    String vr;
    foreach(var v in pay.CardType) {
        vr= v.Selected.ToString();
    }

    return View();
}
```

My question is that how can i get the selected value from my cardtype list when post event is invoked?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add values to your items, not only text:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> getCardTypes()
{
    List<SelectListItem> cardType = new List<SelectListItem>();
    cardType.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "American Express" });
    cardType.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Mastercard" });
    cardType.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Visa" });

    return cardType;
}
```

Now you could simply add a property on your view model:

```
public int SelectedCardType { get; set; }
```

And in the view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedCardType, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["list"]
) %>
```

and in your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Payment(PaymentModels pay)
{
    // pay.SelectedCardType will contain the selected value (1, 2 or 3)
    ...
}
```

Of course the values should not necessary be integers. You could use a string property as well:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> getCardTypes()
{
    List<SelectListItem> cardType = new List<SelectListItem>();
    cardType.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "American Express", Text = "American Express" });
    cardType.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Mastercard", Text = "Mastercard" });
    cardType.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Visa", Text = "Visa" });

    return cardType;
}
```

and:

```
public string SelectedCardType { get; set; }
```